# Removing an author then adding him in a revised manuscript

Tags: paper-submission, science

I submit a revision of a manuscript to a reputable journal and removing one author and changing the order of another author, then the editor sent it back to me to clarify the reasons for changes and ask for signatures from all authors even the removed.can I resubmit it without changes as first? as I am afraid to be rejected

Comment: Why did you try to change the author list after submission??

Comment: Why are you creating this mess for the editor?

Answer (score 8):

Removing authors and changing the author order in a revision is suspicious. There can be perfectly valid reasons for that, but it could also indicate misconduct of the corresponding author. So, asking for explanation and for confirmation from all authors that this is indeed an agreed upon change is very reasonable behaviour of the editor.

If you can provide this, there shouldn't be a problem (provided the explanation makes sense).

If you react by reinstantiating the original author list, it will appear as if you got caught in the attempt to falsify the authorship. Whether or not this will lead to a rejection is something we cannot predict. Now if you indeed were caught trying to falsify the authorship, I neither can nor want to help you.